# How to define routes on Form Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, form-helpers

I have a number of forms that don't match to specific models one to one. I've been using the Form Object pattern (or Decorator, or whatever you want to call it) to power these forms, particularly when there is specific validations that need to happen that don't match to a relevant model validation.

Example:

```
class ProfileClaimRequestForm
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :email, :profile
  delegate :persisted?, :id, to: :profile #??

  validate :matching_emails

  def initialize profile, email = nil
    self.profile = profile
    self.email = email
  end

  private

  def matching_emails
    errors.add(:email, 'The email address entered does not match our records') unless self.email == self.profile.profile.email
  end
end
```

To invoke this I've been using `form_for @form_obj, profile_claim_path(@form_obj.profile.id)` which works fine, however I'm hoping I can DRY up that path declaration. I'm wondering if there is some magic method I can have my form object respond to to define the path or something similar. Ideally I could get it down to `form_for @form_obj`

To note, I'm currently on Rails 3 but we are planning to move to Rails 4 in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `form_for @form_obj`, rails will call `to_param` on the resource, and will use your `resources` definitions from your routes.rb to generate the path. This is helpful if you follow the Rails conventions.

Ex: `form_for @user` will generate `action="/users/1"` (given the user's id was 1)

Now in your case you are not following this convention, so the only way to DRY-up would have been to use nested resources.

If, in your route.rb you would define the resources as this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

Then Rails will generate paths such as `/users/:id/profiles` for example. And you would be able to use this directly with form helper like this `form_for [@user, @profile]`

Long answer short: if you don't follow Rails conventions you must use the long syntax of `form_for` and specify manually the form's target path

Comment: If I had a nested, additional command would I be able to use that convention? 

   `resources profiles do 
      post 'start_claim' 
    end`

Comment: Yes, you can customize your routes in nested resources (see 'collections' and 'members') but I am pretty sure `form_for` will always use the defaults 'create' and 'update' routes for your resource. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more info

Comment: @Drew, so did my answer helped you find your solution?